# How do I make snort stop alerting to auth.log?

Tags: logging, configuration, syslog, snort

I can't seem to get snort to stop logging to syslog (auth.log specifically).  As far as I can tell it seems to be acting as if I'm running with the `-s` argument or with `output alert_syslog: LOG_AUTH LOG_ALERT` in the config.

I'm running snort 2.9.7.0 compiled with `./configure --enable-reload`, and unless there is some hidden option I'm missing, I'm telling it to log to merged.log as unified2, and no place else.

```
snort@snort:~$ ps -ef | grep snort
snort     7524     1  1 18:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -i bond0.566 -l /var/log/snort/bond0.566 -D

snort@snort:~$ grep -R '^output' /etc/snort
/etc/snort/snort.conf:output unified2: filename merged.log, limit 128, mpls_event_types, vlan_event_types
```

Here are some of the logs that I'm seeing

```
snort@snort:~$ tail -n 10 /var/log/auth.log
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [119:31:1] http_inspect: UNKNOWN METHOD [Classification: Unknown Traffic] [Priority: 3]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:32271 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [119:31:1] http_inspect: UNKNOWN METHOD [Classification: Unknown Traffic] [Priority: 3]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:32271 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [129:12:1] stream5: TCP Small Segment Threshold Exceeded [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56534 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [129:12:1] stream5: TCP Small Segment Threshold Exceeded [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:56534 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [129:12:1] stream5: TCP Small Segment Threshold Exceeded [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53271 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [129:12:1] stream5: TCP Small Segment Threshold Exceeded [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53271 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [129:5:1] stream5: Bad segment, overlap adjusted size less than/equal 0 [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53271 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [129:5:1] stream5: Bad segment, overlap adjusted size less than/equal 0 [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53271 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [129:12:1] stream5: TCP Small Segment Threshold Exceeded [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2443 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
Feb 10 18:31:15 snort.example.com snort[32353]: [129:12:1] stream5: TCP Small Segment Threshold Exceeded [Classification: Potentially Bad Traffic] [Priority: 2]: <bond0.566> {TCP} xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2443 -> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
```

Most of these alerts are garbage that I will filter out later, the alerts themselves don't bother me, what bothers me is that they are going to auth.log and I can't figure out why.

Comment: These are all decoder and preprocessor rules (http://manual.snort.org/node18.html) that are alerting. Do you have the option "disable_decode_alerts" in the snort.conf? If not you want to try adding this if you want the alerts to stop. I'm still not 100% sure why these are alerting to syslog though, as far as I know they should still be logged the same as the normal rules.

Comment: I do have "config disable_decode_alerts" in my config.  Right now the config I'm using is about 99% stock from the 2.9.7.0 tar.gz.  Basically I changed a few ipvar and path vars, and enabled unified2 logging.

Comment: Just double checking, but the pid in the output of ps is different than the pid in the logs, is that just because snort was restarted and the log messages are from a newer process? Otherwise there's another snort process running that's not in ps output?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just a process restart.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check to make sure that snort is actually the responsible process for generating those logs. I've seen cases where [barnyard2](https://github.com/firnsy/barnyard2) appears in the logs as if it was snort generating the logs, which would throw anyone off. In /etc/barnyard2.conf, or whatever your config file is, you will probably see a line telling to send alerts to syslog, much like this:

```
output alert_syslog: LOG_AUTH LOG_INFO
```

You'll want to edit that line so barnyard2 will log how you want it to.